# The synonym of "the smallest one" as a single word

Tags: synonyms

I wanted to know if there any single word that replaces "the smallest one", like minor or tiny or some words like that. And the replacement should be a noun.

**Edit:**
I need a noun that expresses the minimality of something, it might not be the smallest, it could be the youngest or the lowest etc. but it should be noun.
Or let's say that we have set of elements those have size and could be measured, and there should be a noun that expresses the smallest element of this set.
*Like rookie is at the bottom of the army (the smallest) and the general is at the top of the army or policy (the highest or the biggest one)*. But in this example rookie has not size its measurement mostly depends on an experience or things like that.

Comment: You want the word ***least***. For a famous example, in the Bible, the verse Matthew 25:40 reads (in part): *Truly I tell you, whatever you did for the **least** of my brothers, you did for me.*

Comment: You're not generally going to be able to eliminate the article.

Comment: @DanBron, You are replacing ***the smallest*** with the ***the least*** in your example.

Comment: @pyramidPeak As HotLicks says, the article is going to have to stay. You can omit it, but that doesn't depend on what word you choose to indicate minimum: any such word will do, and the omission will scan for native speakers like headlinese.

Comment: But "smallest" has numerous synonyms -- "tiniest", "littlest", "least", "slightest", etc.

Comment: Your edit makes things even less clear.

Comment: @HotLicks I am not native english speaker, and it is being a bit difficult to explain what I need. But your examples are adjectives not nouns. Let me show another example to make it more clear what I need. e.g. If I am not mistaken the youngest child in family could be called like ***junior***

Comment: @pyramidPeak 'junior' is an adjective "Bob is the junior member of the family". Another way of asking is to give a sentence with a blank in the place of the word you are seeking. Please add a couple examples to your question.

Comment: Most terms of this class can be used as nouns.  Note that "junior" is an adjective.

Comment: Like [runt](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/runt)?

Comment: @Davo, yes like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Runt](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/runt)** may be acceptable for your use.

> A small pig or other animal, especially the smallest in a litter.